# Adsense or Google Doubleclick with meteor.js

Tags: meteor, iron-router, adsense, meteor-helper, double-click-advertising

Is anyone succesfully adding adsense (loads with each pageview) or even better, with doubleclick (DFP)?

No matter what I try I cannot get them to show anywhere.

Comment: If you're using `iron:router` there are packages available for google analytics with full documentation.  One that I have used with success is https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/iron-router-ga

Comment: That's for for GA hehe. Although good to know there's an easy way for content experiments with Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Adsense as follows. This use the `iron:router` package.

```
<template name="MyAds">
  <div class="leaderboard"></div>
</template>

Template.MyAds.rendered = function() {
  $.getScript("//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js", function() {
    var ads, adsbygoogle;
    ads = '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block" data-ad-client="ca-pub-72414***074839" data-ad-slot="4009***57" data-ad-format="auto"></ins>';
    $('.leaderboard').html(ads);
    return (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  });
};

Router.map( function () {
  this.route('MyRoute', {
    waitOn: function() {
      return IRLibLoader.load("//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js");
    }
  });
});
```

See here for more info: https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-18-add-google-adsense-to-your-application/37

Comment: Hmm... I tried them both separately and not at the same time before, thus couldn't get it to work. Thank you so much for your answer! I think I can get DFP working with this also.

Comment: Although on the 6th page refresh the javascript fails to loads, thus the ad doesn't load either? Added the async script to head and to every route, but didn't fix it.

Comment: Is there something special about the number 6?

Comment: Nope, just fails to load after the 6th page view.

Comment: It's consistently the 6th page. That just sounds strange. Is it a specific page you're going to? It never happens 5th or 7th time?

Comment: Actually happens on the 6th load and then it doesn't load until a hard refresh.

Comment: Do some prints to the console to try see what's happening

Comment: I get a 404 error: https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/favicon?q=tbn:ANd9GcT4BdJ8cp5agaPqUNA-

Comment: Google that error. I'm sure another SO question deals with it